# How to rotate texture in webGL

Tags: webgl, webgl2

I am capturing texture from a web cam into webGl in the browser, its rotation is normal when I display in the browser using the Video element, but when it gets in to webGL the texture is rotated -90 degrees.

How can I rotate the texture 90 degrees so it goes back to normal orientation?

```
function updateTexture(gl, texture, video) {
  const level = 0;
  const internalFormat = gl.RGBA;
  const srcFormat = gl.RGBA;
  const srcType = gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE;
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, level, internalFormat,
                srcFormat, srcType, video);
}
```

Comment: Try rotating the textured surface instead of the texture itself.

Comment: Is it really 90 degrees? Usually people experience a horizontal mirror due to the way webgl addresses the pixel array, setting the texture parameter `UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL` solves this, otherwise [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35598494/webgl-texture-flip-horizontally) will provide you with a solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Webgl texture flip horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35598494/webgl-texture-flip-horizontally)